# Generate mxml file from excel file

Tags: excel, apache-flex, code-generation

How to generate mxml(flex code) from excel file.
how to Create flex code from xls file.

Comment: Normally you wouldn't want to do this.  Excel is a horrible IDE for writing Flex code.

Comment: I want to read excel file and generate mxml file as the fields specified in excel (tabbar,text box or button fields),i mean tosay the layout should come from excel file(eg. like code generator for flex using excel)

Comment: Basically Excel is having controls , i want to read excel and generate flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use Excel to create the data that you want instead of the application you want. Use excel to generate a .csv or the xml that represents your data in away that Flex can easily consume it.

If you want to use excel to actually be some sort of code generator, I wouldn't say it's impossible but the effort behind it would not be of any monetary benefit. You have to write up a custom mapper (that does not exist) that will generate .mxml markup document.

Comment: How to Consume xml data in flex?how can we do that?

Comment: do you know how to create a custom mapper for flex?

Comment: How to consume XML data in Flex? Stack overflow will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941842/reading-data-from-xml-file-in-flex

Comment: A custom mapper would involve taking the output of Excel (.xls, .csv, .xml, etc) and creating a mapping against entities that exist in MXML. But then you would also have to deal with if open tags will be properly closed. Going through this approach is a bad idea because there is probably some other approach that would achieve your desired goal for way less effort.